# Wordpress: Script error pushing head content into body

Tags: wordpress, head

okay I am really stumped on this one. I am developing a wordpress site right now where the other day, sort of out of nowhere I started noticing style related issues occurring, content being pushed way down and flex-box content no longer reading 100% height correctly which led me to do some deeper digging. Upon digging I noticed a weird text string appearing inside the view source & in the html of the site before the doctype

```
    {"status":0,"redirect":""}
```

So I went searching everywhere to figure out what could be causing this, I googled for what felt like an eternity but to no avail. I then went through all of my php & html looking for anything that could cause this, still nothing. Then I begun slowly disabling wordpress plugins one after the other, still nothing. I even loaded up a new theme thinking maybe it could be theme related, nope, still shows. Then I went the pyscho route, disabled every plugin knowing it would break the site... refresh page, blank page... with one exception, that empty text string is still there. WTH?
 Then I begun looking further & noticed something even more disturbing, some script, some evil devil script is causing all the content within my  tags, to be loaded into the body tag after the site loads. Now if you view source, you can see the code still looks fine at that point (minus the one weird string at the beginning) but once the dom gets it, boom... everything fubar.
 So here is the site URL http://marsvinyl.com/vinyl (although every page has the same issue).

[text string and content issues photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiYLr.jpg)

I'm not sure where to go from here guys, I have googled, run through as many stack overflow pages as humanly possible, disabled, reloaded, etc... HELP! I've never seen anything like this in all of my years of this.

Comment: If none of the plugins nor your theme is causing this, sounds like you have some malware installed deep in WordPress or even somewhere else in your server. Install an antimalware plugin (eg. Sucuri, Wordfence, etc) and run a scan.

Comment: That was it bud! I ran Sucuri & it found a couple of core modified files & BOOM! You rule Cabrerahector!!!!

Comment: Now that you know what the problem is: clean up your site; upgrade WordPress, themes and plugins to the latest version available; run another scan just in case; make sure everything you have installed on your site comes from trusted / recognized developers; and, last but not least, update all of your passwords (and use strong ones!)